# Pasted text appears in anchor tag

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

When we paste text from Microsoft word in ckeditor5, sometimes pasted text appears under ** anchor tag ** when it is not link in office. Is there any config to override that?
This mainly happens on or after 2nd copy and paste from word.

The do for pasted text looks like below:

```
<a name="OLE_LINK47">
    <span style="font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:24.0pt;">
        <span style="mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-bookmark:OLE_LINK46;" lang="EN-US" dir="ltr">This is a dummy text</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: You probably just need to paste as plain text. Use ctrl/cmd + shift + v?

Comment: But with that other formatting is lost as well.